# Reversing a switch statement

Tags: c#

I'm working on some inherited code and I've got a function that is converting between to formats of swing weight (a golf club term, for you non-golf folk). This function converts between a letter/float format (e.g., C3.1, E4.5, etc) to a decimal format (e.g., 20.15). It's not an intuitive conversion as you will see below in the switch statement that performs the conversion. My problem is that the code only has this one-way conversion (from C8.9 to 20.15), and now I need to reverse this (from 20.15 to C8.9), so if a solution to this is more apparent to anybody than it is to me, I'd love to hear your suggestion. If this is not the right place for this type of question, let me know and I'll move it.

```
    // lorythmicSwingWeight will be in the Letter/Float format, e.g. D3.0
    internal static decimal ioSW(string lorythmicSwingWeight)
    {
        string lSW_alpha = string.Empty;
        decimal lSW_num = 0.0m;
        decimal oSW = 0.0m;

        //parse first letter
        lSW_alpha = lorythmicSwingWeight.Trim().ToUpper().Substring(0, 1);
        //try to parse number
        decimal.TryParse(lorythmicSwingWeight.Substring(1), out lSW_num);

        switch (lSW_alpha)
        {
            case "A":
                if (lSW_num < 10)
                    oSW = (20000m * lSW_num + 1710329m) / 112300m;
                break;
            case "B":
                if (lSW_num < 4.0m)
                    oSW = (500m * lSW_num + 50371m) / 2963m;
                else if (lSW_num < 10)
                    oSW = (250m * lSW_num + 25449m) / 1497m;
                break;
            case "C":
                if (lSW_num < 1.7m)
                    oSW = (4000m * lSW_num + 409927m) / 21980m;
                else if (lSW_num < 5.3m)
                    oSW = (800m * lSW_num + 86909m) / 4660m;
                else if (lSW_num < 10m)
                    oSW = (200m * lSW_num + 21902m) / 1175m;
                break;
            case "D":
                if (lSW_num < 2.2m)
                    oSW = (10000m * lSW_num + 1242163m) / 61100m;
                else if (lSW_num < 5.0m)
                    oSW = (5000m * lSW_num + 621387m) / 30550m;
                else if (lSW_num < 8.5m)
                    oSW = (2000m * lSW_num + 248677m) / 12220m;
                else if (lSW_num < 10m)
                    oSW = (2500m * lSW_num + 310999m) / 15275m;
                break;
            case "E":
                if (lSW_num < 4.0m)
                    oSW = (100m * lSW_num + 13222m) / 601m;
                else if (lSW_num < 10m)
                    oSW = (10000m * lSW_num + 1317201m) / 59900m;
                break;
        }

        oSW = Math.Round(oSW, 2);
        return oSW; // this will spit out a decimal, e.g. 20.15
    }
```

Comment: Is the reverse operation even a function?  By that I mean will every specific decimal format map to exactly one lorythmic weight?

Comment: if these are supposed to be logrythmic, why not use the `Math` class to perform actual logrythms?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I believe it's one-to-one, I have a chart that goes along with this.. it occurs to me now that instead of figuring out a clever way to do this, I could more easily just cross-reference the chart in a manner of speaking.

Comment: @Aravol it's not logrythmic, lorythmic is not a typo.

Comment: @Andy got it. If you cross-reference a chart, be aware there are some pretty nasty quirks when it comes to comparing non-integer values in code, and you'll want to round more than perform a simple lookup

Comment: @Aravol good point, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with thing a reverse calculation is that, at least mathematically, there could be two results for any given input. Disclaimer: I am not a golf person, so this is taking it from a high-level logical analysis.

Because of the ambiguity, your best bet may be to simply run the calculation on the result *per* letter, thus getting an `A__` result, a `B__` result, a `C__` result... ect. Since you have to perform some `if` checks in applying the math the first time, you might even need more than one such result per letter, but then start chucking results which don't match presumptions - this the result for an `A` with `lWS_sum < 10` could be chucked if the reverse of that stage math (`oSW = (20000m * lSW_num + 1710329m) / 112300m;`) came out greater than ten.

From there, you'll have a list of *possible* results. Order them by string length, and take the first.

Comment: I'm not a golf person either, but this sounds like it should work just fine for this application